# Integration of Sharepoint 2007 and bootstrap failure

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to integrate MOSS 2007 with bootstrap and create my own site design. I met some problems with that and maybe you can help me a little:

I have done my own master template and it looks pretty good on default page, but I have problem with styling for example List View page.

I can give you example of my problem:

this is part of master containing PlaceHolderMain:

```
<div class="container main-container">
    <div id="loginPanel" class="row" >
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
```

According to that I have tried to make page max-width of 750px

```
.container { max-width: 750px; }
```

This is how it looks with list view(Note that all table is placed in div which has 750px width, and table itself has computed width 791 in this case)

[image: How it looks with lists]

I have been trying to make for example:

```
.row table{
    max-width: 750px;
}
```

but it does not work. I was also trying to make

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

but it screwed all Sharepoint site

Do you have any hints for that problem?

Help please :)